# How do I make all descendant folders picture-view folders in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

There's a "picture view" for Windows XP folders.  I keep creating new folders in a directory and adding pictures to them.

Every time I create a new folder, I have to go through the added action of creating a new text document named `description.txt` and then setting the folder to `picture view` mode (`dropdown: view->picture`).  I don't mind the keystrokes, but I want to be a Super User!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The info about folder view is stored in the registry, not the folder itself.

Comment: Could I alter the registry for a folder and all its descendants to give them a default `folder view`?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 No, because it’s an undocumented compressed binary structure.